# F# Shortcut Syntax for Properties?

Tags: f#

For the normal property getter/setter syntax

```
let mutable myInternalValue

member this.MyProperty 
    with get() = myInternalValue
    and set(value) = myInternalValue <- value
```

is there a shortcut, similar to the following in C#?

```
someType MyProperty { get; set; }
```

If there is one, I seem to be unable to find it...

Answer (score 61, accepted):

F# 3 has **auto-implemented properties** so you can declare properties without declaring the backing field.

Example taken from [Properties(F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/dd483467.aspx) on MSDN:

```
type MyClass() =
    member val MyProperty = "" with get, set
```

Comment: Note the syntax for abstract properties, i.e. properties declared by an interface, is completely different using `abstract` as a prefix keyword, omitting the `val` keyword, but _optionally_ retaining the `member` keyword...

Answer (score 12):

There is no shortcut for creating `get`/`set` property in F#, but if you want a property with just `get` you can use the following simple syntax:

```
type Test(n) =
  let myValue = n * 2
  member x.Property = 
    // Evaluated each time you access property value
    myValue + 5
```

Since F# is a functional language, F# types are very often immutable. This syntax makes it very easy to define immutable types, so it also encourages you to use a good functional programming style in F#.

However, I agree that a shortcut for `get`/`set` property would be very useful, especially when writing some code that needs to interoperate with C# / other .NET libraries.

**EDIT** (5 years later...): This has been added in F# 3.0, as the answer from Ben shows :-)

Comment: So you say it's an educational measure? What I think is a bit tedious (and was in the first versions of C#) is the need to write the internal value explicitly, and the short C# syntax also makes it easy to have getters/setters with different access modifiers. Not saying I can't live with the current state of affairs, it's a minor point, really.

Comment: @Alexander: I wouldn't really say that the motivation for not having easy syntax for `get`/`set` properties is educational. It's probably a matter of priorities for the F# team. Adding support for mutable properties would be more work, but I agree it would be really useful.

Comment: @Alexander--not quite sure of the scenario but as I see more and more code where people mindlessly add getters and setters (or inspectors and mutators as I've sometimes heard them call) that do nothing other than return the value or change it, it's harder and harder to justify not just making the values public members.  I mean code that doesn't hide the type behind some typedef and simply reads a member from a class and simply sets the value in the class might just as well be public--it's coupled just the same after all.  Maybe it's a good thing that F# forces you to add this if you want it.

Comment: @Onorio: True. I remember this first came up with C++/COM in order to facilitate the marshalling of objects or some such and has now somehow taken hold as something that just is A Good Thing and needs always be done. I guess the remaining rationale is that you do it "just in case" you need to change the internal implementation in the future.

Comment: An alternative option is to create a local reference cell and expose it using member. `let local = ref 10` and `member x.Prop = local` (note that you need two lines - because member body is evaluated each time it is used). But .NET properties are certainly more idiomatic.

Comment: @Onorio Catenacci: simple getters and setters rather than public fields are often necessary in order to benefit from things like ASP.NET / WPF data-binding and XML serialization. C# 3.0 eased the boiler-plate required for these scenarios with Auto-Implemented Properties.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a shortcut, similar to the following in C#?

I don't think so (nothing shown in "Expert F#"'s syntax summary), and the F# syntax is already quite brief compared to the full syntax needed in C#.