# Using IRepository interfaces in f#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#, f#-3.0

I'm currently rewriting a graduate student project that was written in c# to f#.

I'm stumped on how to handle IRepository interfaces in f#.  It seems trivial in c#, but f# doesn't like what I've done.

The IRepository in question is defined in the myNameSpace.SolarSystem name space. Which I make sure to include in my f# project.

Here are my notes:

**f# - invalid use of an interface type** <--(`let repo = IRepository<SolarSystem>()`)

```
open myNameSpace.SolarSystem

let searchCatalog = [| 8; 11; 31 |]

let repo = IRepository<SolarSystem>()

let ClassOfSolarSystems classOfStar = 
    repo.Query().Where(fun s -> s.SolarGroups.Any(fun c -> searchCatalog.Contains(classOfStar) ))
```

**c# - no error:**

```
using myNameSpace.SolarSystem

private readonly int[]  searchCatalog = new int[] { 8, 11, 31 };

public IRepository<SolarSystem> Repo { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SolarSystem> ClassOfSolarSystems(Int32 classOfStar)
{
    return Repo.Query()
    .Where(s => s.SolarGroups.Any(c =>   searchCatalog.Contains(classOfStar)));
}
```

I exhausted my googlefu and could not find any meaningful(to me at least) solutions.

Is there a way to use IRepository interfaces in f#?

Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't look like valid C# code. Did you leave out something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your F# line is equivalent to this C#, as the keyword `new` is implicit in F#.

```
var repo = new IRepository<SolarSystem>()
```

The C# compiler would not let you do that either. Also, your C# example is a property, while in F# it is a value binding. [To define properties in F# you need to use the `member` keyword.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913623/f-shortcut-syntax-for-properties)

Edit

I played around with the editor a bit until I found something the compiler was mildly happy about, came up with this.

```
let ClassOfSolarSystems (repo : IRepository<SolarSystem>) classOfStar = 
    repo.Query()
    |> Seq.filter(fun s -> s.SolarGroups.Any(fun c -> searchCatalog.Contains(classOfStar) ))
```

I didn't mess too much with your LINQ expressions but you should consider using the [F# `Seq` module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.seq-module-%5Bfsharp%5D) instead.

Comment: "I didn't mess too much with your LINQ expressions but you should consider using the F# Seq module instead."  Actually, I'd prefer for that [F# Query Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/query-expressions-%5Bfsharp%5D).

Comment: I don't think query expressions would improve much here, though.

Comment: @JoelMueller Baby steps

Comment: Why change `Enumerable.Where` to `Seq.filter` but not `Enumerable.Any` to `Seq.exists` or `Enumerable.Contains` to `Seq.contains`? `|> Seq.filter (fun s -> s.SolarGroups |> Seq.exists (fun c -> Seq.contains classOfStar searchCatalog))`

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
let repo = IRepository<SolarSystem>()
```

you try to create an instance of the interface, as you well know, it is impossible.

Just create a function that takes a repository and search parameters.

```
open SolarSystems
open System.Linq

type RepositoryFunctions =
    member this.ClassOfSolarSystems (repo:IRepository<SolarSystem>) (classOfStar:int32) =
                                       repo.Query().Where(fun s -> s.SolarGroups.Any(fun c -> searchCatalog.Contains(classOfStar) ))
```

So, if you not prefer to use LINQ in F#, you can write:

```
open SolarSystems

type RepositoryFunctions =
    member this.ClassOfSolarSystems (repo:IRepository<SolarSystem>) (classOfStar:int32) =
                 let catalogContainsStar searchCatalog = searchCatalog.Contains(classOfStar)
                 let systemContainsStar solarSys = solarSys.SolarGroups.Any( catalogContainsStar )
                 let getAllWithStar = Seq.filter systemContainsStar
                 in
                   repo.Query() |> getAllWithStar
```